# please help me solve the following problem through recursion

Tags: recursion

Given four integers A, B, C, D. A represents the initial position of the geek on the x-axis. In each step, geek can go to X+B or X-B if he is standing at X. The tasks is to check if it is possible for the geek to reach C exactly after D steps.

Input:

1. The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
2. The first line of each test case contains four space-separated integers A, B, C, and D.

Output: For each test case, print "yes" if it is possible to reach C in exactly D steps. Otherwise, print "no" (without quotes).

Constraints:

1. 1 <= T <= 5
2. -10^9 <= A, C <= 10^9
3. 1 <= B <= 10^9
4. 1 <= D <= 15

Example:
Input:
3
2 3 8 4
-3 1 0 3
-3 1 1 3

Output:
yes
yes
no

Comment: The way you described the problem, it does not sound as if you need any recursion. Check my proposed solution below or clarify the question further please.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer in addition to upvoting :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you need any recursion for this problem, it's simply a matter of checking:

```py
q, r = divmod(int(A - C), B)
q <= D and r == 0
```